# Xively displays incorrect timestamp when logged out

Tags: xively

When I'm logged into Xively, it shows the correct timestamps for my feed. When I'm not logged in, it shows an incorrect timestamp. For the record, this is a dust sensor connected to an Arduino Ethernet. The Arduino doesn't set the timestamp itself (it relies on Xively for that).

Am I doing something wrong to cause this unexpected behavior? Or is this a Xively bug?

**Correct timestamp is shown when I'm logged in:** [image]

**Incorrect timestamp is shown when I'm NOT logged in - I think it defaults to UTC** [image]